# How to zoom out on embedded google map on chrome webpage in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I want to zoom out on an embedded google map in a chrome webpage using selenium. I have tried the following with different location  and scaling tweaks but neither works for me. I am able to zoom-out on the page but not on the map so that it reloads with new markers covering the a new map area.

```
browser.send_cmd('Input.synthesizePinchGesture', {
                        'x': 500,
                        'y': 200,
                        'scaleFactor': 0.5,
                        'relativeSpeed': 800, # optional                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                        'gestureSourceType': 'default' # optional                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    })
```

and

```
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='0.5'")
```

Is there another solution ?